# Parse a big JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

So I have a quite big JSON string which has a pretty advanced structure (at least for me) that I want to parse with javascript. Here is a reader-friendly version of it (which is an example) :

```
   {
  "list": {
    "pagination": {
      "count": 0,
      "hasMoreItems": true,
      "totalItems": 0,
      "skipCount": 0,
      "maxItems": 0
    },
    "entries": [
      {
        "entry": {
          "id": "string",
          "firstName": "string",
          "lastName": "string",
          "description": "string",
          "avatarId": "string",
          "email": "string",
          "skypeId": "string",
          "googleId": "string",
          "instantMessageId": "string",
          "jobTitle": "string",
          "location": "string",
          "company": {
            "organization": "string",
            "address1": "string",
            "address2": "string",
            "address3": "string",
            "postcode": "string",
            "telephone": "string",
            "fax": "string",
            "email": "string"
          },
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I really get and want to parse is, if you want to take a look at it, this string (which contains 7 "entry"):

```
{"list":{"pagination":{"count":7,"hasMoreItems":false,"totalItems":7,"skipCount":0,"maxItems":100},"entries":[{"entry":{"lastName":"Beecher","userStatus":"Helping to design the look and feel of the new web site","jobTitle":"Graphic Designer","statusUpdatedAt":"2011-02-15T20:20:13.432+0000","mobile":"0112211001100","emailNotificationsEnabled":true,"description":"Alice is a demo user for the sample Alfresco Team site.","telephone":"0112211001100","enabled":false,"firstName":"Alice","skypeId":"abeecher","avatarId":"198500fc-1e99-4f5f-8926-248cea433366","location":"Tilbury, UK","company":{"organization":"Moresby, Garland and Wedge","address1":"200 Butterwick Street","address2":"Tilbury","address3":"UK","postcode":"ALF1 SAM1"},"id":"abeecher","email":"abeecher@example.com"}},{"entry":{"firstName":"Administrator","emailNotificationsEnabled":true,"company":{},"id":"admin","enabled":true,"email":"admin@alfresco.com"}},{"entry":{"firstName":"Alex","lastName":"lol","emailNotificationsEnabled":true,"company":{},"id":"alexandra","enabled":true,"email":"alexandra.lol@test.com"}},{"entry":{"firstName":"Guest","emailNotificationsEnabled":true,"company":{},"id":"guest","enabled":false}},{"entry":{"firstName":"Jack","lastName":"lol","emailNotificationsEnabled":true,"company":{},"id":"jack","enabled":true,"email":"jack.lol@test.com"}},{"entry":{"lastName":"Jackson","userStatus":"Working on a new web design for the corporate site","jobTitle":"Web Site Manager","statusUpdatedAt":"2011-02-15T20:13:09.649+0000","mobile":"012211331100","emailNotificationsEnabled":true,"description":"Mike is a demo user for the sample Alfresco Team site.","telephone":"012211331100","enabled":false,"firstName":"Mike","skypeId":"mjackson","avatarId":"3fbde500-298b-4e80-ae50-e65a5cbc2c4d","location":"Threepwood, UK","company":{"organization":"Green Energy","address1":"100 Cavendish Street","address2":"Threepwood","address3":"UK","postcode":"ALF1 SAM1"},"id":"mjackson","email":"mjackson@example.com"}},{"entry":{"firstName":"Nicolas","lastName":"lol","emailNotificationsEnabled":true,"company":{},"id":"nicolas","enabled":true,"email":"nicolas.lol@test.com"}}]}}
```

So my code to parse it is

```
<div id="liste"></div>
<script>
        var objet = JSON.parse('***[....Big string....]***');
        document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML = objet.firstName;
</script>
```

So I tried a lot of combinations such as objet.entries.entry.firstName or objet.entries[1] (which gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`)... 
But I still don't how to reach my goal of getting just .firtName for example. And I only find simple examples of JSONparse() on the internet such as strings like this `{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":"555-0100"}` so..

If anyone knows thank in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I tried a lot of combinations such as objet.entries.entry.firstName or objet.entries[1] (which gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined)

The first element of a javascript array is the element at index `0` - so you simply wanted:

```
var firstName = objet.list.entries[0].entry.firstName
```

Comment: This actually gives me the same error, I changed `document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML = objet.entries[0].entry.firstName;` and I still get that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Ok thank you, you were right, it wasn't the structure i expected, i added "list" and it worked : `objet.list.entries[0].entry.firstName ` But, just to be sure in future code, with the example I gave I shouldn't add "list" ?

Comment: @JackA I think I actually missed the `list` in your json, not you. Sorry about that